# Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'StoresSummaryResults'. Property 'Data' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, observable

I am new to using the Observable with Angular 2 and my structure will not receive the results, even though I can validate the response from my REST API.

I have the following data class in Typescript.

```
import { RESTResult } from '../common/RESTResult';        // Common Response Structure
import { StoresSummaryData } from './StoresSummaryData';  // Structure of records being returned as an array

export class StoresSummaryResults extends RESTResult {
    Data: Array<StoresSummaryData>;     // Data[] is array ofStoresSummaryData structure ({ field1, field2 ...)

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.Data = new Array<StoresSummaryData>();    // Ensure 1 records exists for testing
        this.Data.push(new StoresSummaryData(0, 0));
    }
}
```

The results are retrieved from the REST API

```
getResults(): Observable<StoresSummaryResults> {    // Structure 
    return this.http.get(this.RequestHttpPath)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
};

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}

StoreInfo: StoresSummaryResults;
public constructor(private storesService: StoresService) { }
showResults(): void {
    this.StoreInfo = this.storesService.getResults();
}
```

I get the error:

```
Typescript Error
Type 'Observable<StoresSummaryResults>' is not assignable to type 'StoresSummaryResults'. Property 'Data' is missing in type 'Observable<StoresSummaryResults>'.
```

I do have the Data structure though defined, so I am not sure what to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `StoreInfo` property is typed as a `StoresSummaryResults`, but you are trying to assign it the return value of `storesService.getResults()` which is `Observable<StoresSummaryResults>`.

So either change `StoreInfo` to be typed as `Observable<StoresSummaryResults>`, or assign it in a subscription:

```
this.storeSevice.getResults()
    .subscribe(results => this.StoreInfo = results);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  That corrects my error.  In testing the code earlier, I had the definition with Observable<StoreInfo> but just received the error in another part of the code.  I was trying to verify my code without the HTTP call.  In trying to simply return `Result = new Observable<StoreInfo>()` I cannot add items to the StoreInfo structure.  I am not sure how to test this easily by adding a structure.

Comment: You can certainly do that, but you'd want to construct whatever class includes the `StoreInfo` property (you didn't include the definition) in the `subscribe()`. That way, the class itself doesn't have to wait for the result. Or you can test it by mocking `storeService` to return `Observable.return(storeInfoValue)`.